# what happen, my code cannot display result after parse XML in Go Lang?

Tags: go

I have XML like this

[here my code XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQWPu.png)

my description is correct or not  with my code below :

```
type CustomerAndy struct {
    XMLName         xml.Name    `xml:"b:RelatedPartyList"`
    CustomerAndy    []DataLengkap   `xml:"b:RelatedParty"`
}

type DataLengkap struct {
    XMLNAME   xml.Name `xml:"b:RelatedParty"`
    FullName    string  `xml:"b:FullName"`
    Ktp         string  `xml:"b:IDNumber"`
    PefindoId   string  `xml:"b:CreditinfoId"`
    Address     string  `xml:"c:AddressLine"`

}
```

and this my full code go lang  to parse XML :

[here my full code go lang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6F0l.png)

why my code , I have change any way ,without looping, with looping, but not display result from parse XML , what wrong with my code ?

Comment: Don't post images. Post text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unmarshal-ing, remove the XML namespace (`xmlns`) prefixes. e.g.

```
type CustomerAndy struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name      `xml:"RelatedPartyList"`
    CustomerAndy []DataLengkap `xml:"RelatedParty"`
}
```

`xml.Unmarshal` already handles the namespaces.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to help other people who might answer this by putting text rather than images.

Comment: hi my xml is huge files xml , if code xml short is run with your way , but if  code is huge files xml, cannot run why ?

Comment: I cannot check this without a view of your input file.

Comment: I'd add that when needed, it's possible to specify XML namespaces on field tags but the namespaces must be spelled in full and separated from the node name by a single space character.